# Get the value from a nested object of json without creating an extra class

Tags: json, api, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I have a class called **Post** which will have `categories` property as follows

```
data class Post (
    @SerializedName("id")
    val idPost: String?,
    val categories: Category?
)
data class Category(
    val id: String?,
    val label: String?
)
```

And my JSON

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "categories": 
        {
            "id": "123",
            "label": "XYZ"
        },
    ...
}
```

Now I wonder whether can I do it differently. I need only the id from categories.
I tried

```
data class Post (
    @SerializedName("id")
    val idPost: String?,
    @SerializedName("categories.id")
    val categories: String?
)
```

but it doesn't work. 
Can I get the value from a nested object of json without creating an extra class?

Comment: you could use [klaxon's streaming api](https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon#streaming-api) for that purpose.

Comment: Yes you can but that would mix the way you parse the payload. You are way better of creating that class.

Edit: Plus you should avoid mixing your business classes and data transfer objects.
Use versioned [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)s and data mappers to prevent your core app from inheriting intricate models of your current API.